# Creating classes with a reference to the parent class - best practices

Tags: vba

I have been struggling for a long time with the problem of how to properly create a class with a reference to the parent class so that when deleting the parent object, all child objects are also deleted. I will try to demonstrate this in the example below.

Let's say I have a simple child class 'ClassChild' like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TChild
    Field1 As String
End Type

Private this As TChild

Public Property Get Field1() As String
    Field1 = this.Field1
End Property
    
Public Property Let Field1(Field1 As String)
    this.Field1 = Field1
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "ClassChild_Terminate" & this.Field1
End Sub
```

To collect a collection of objects of this class, I create a parent class 'ClassParent'.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TParent
    Childs As Collection
End Type

Private this As TParent

Public Property Get Item(vItem As Variant) As ClassChild
   Set Item = this.Childs(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
   Count = this.Childs.Count
End Property

Public Property Get Childs() As Collection
   Set Childs = this.Childs
End Property

Public Sub Add(Child As ClassChild)
   this.Childs.Add Child, CStr(Child.Field1)
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(vItem As Variant)
   this.Childs.Remove vItem
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Childs = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "ClassParent_Terminate"
End Sub
```

With such a design, everything works correctly and in accordance with my expectations.

```
Sub testClassParent()
Dim Parent As ClassParent
Dim Child As ClassChild
Dim i As Integer

    Set Parent = New ClassParent
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set Child = New ClassChild
        Child.Field1 = CStr(i)
        Parent.Add Child
        Set Child = Nothing
    Next
    
    Set Parent = Nothing
End Sub
```

When a Parent object ends its life, all child objects are also deleted from memory.

```
'Immediate
ClassChild_Terminate1
ClassChild_Terminate2
ClassChild_Terminate3
ClassChild_Terminate4
ClassChild_Terminate5
ClassParent_Terminate
```

The problem arises when I want the Child class to have a reference to its parent class. So I add a few lines to both the ClassChild and ClassParent

```
'ClassChild 
Option Explicit

Private Type TChild
    Field1 As String
    Parent As ClassParent
End Type

Private this As TChild

Public Property Get Field1() As String
    Field1 = this.Field1
End Property
    
Public Property Let Field1(Field1 As String)
    this.Field1 = Field1
End Property

Public Property Get Parent() As ClassParent
    Set Parent = this.Parent
End Property
    
Public Property Set Parent(Parent As ClassParent)
    Set this.Parent = Parent
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "ClassChild_Terminate" & this.Field1
End Sub


'ClassParent
Option Explicit

Private Type TParent
    Childs As Collection
End Type

Private this As TParent

Public Property Get Item(vItem As Variant) As ClassChild
   Set Item = this.Childs(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
   Count = this.Childs.Count
End Property

Public Property Get Childs() As Collection
   Set Childs = this.Childs
End Property

Public Sub Add(Child As ClassChild)
    Set Child.Parent = Me
    this.Childs.Add Child, CStr(Child.Field1)
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(vItem As Variant)
   this.Childs.Remove vItem
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Childs = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "ClassParent_Terminate"
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, with this construction, whenever I want to remove a Parent with Set Parent = Nothing, none of the Child objects are removed from memory.

Up until now, I've always written an extra explicit Terminate method like the one below

```
Public Sub Terminate()
Dim Child As ClassChild

    Do While this.Childs.Count > 0
        Set Child = this.Childs.Item(1)
        Set Child.Parent = Nothing
        this.Childs.Remove (1)
        Set Child = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub
```

And now when I want to delete the Parent object I do this

```
    Parent.Terminate
    Set Parent = Nothing
```

And now finally my question. Can it be done better/differently more correctly? I will be grateful for any suggestions.

P.S.
Please forgive me if the code is a bit long. I tried to write it as simply as possible to show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA uses reference counting to dispose of objects in memory. Objects remain in memory so long as there as at least one object variable pointing to it. Since you are referencing a child from the parent, and a parent from a child, you have built a so called circular reference, which can only be removed by manually removing the references / objects from memory, which you actually showcase in your last step.